# event.preventDefault(); is not working on Firefox on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, submit, jquery-events

I had a form as below:

```
    <form name="attachment_form" id="id_attachment_form" class='class_attachment_form' action="/visit/something/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class="datagrid item_list" id="id_attachments">
            <tbody>
                    <td>
                        *Accession Number: <input id='acc_number' type="text" name="accession_number">
                    </td>                
            </tbody> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#id_attachment_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var accession_number = $('#acc_number').val();
        if (!accession_number)
            {
              alert("Please provide Accession Number");
              console.log('redirecting===>1');
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log('redirecting===>2');
            }
        else
            {    
                var url = '/visit/' + accession_number
                $(".class_attachment_form").attr("action", url);
                
            }
    });

});
    
</script>
```

So when I tried this on Firefox and submitted the form without value for `Accession Number` it was displaying the pop-up with some message, but it was also redirecting to url in the form action attribute `event.preventDefault();` is not working, its not stopping the form redirection.

Similarly when I tried the same procedure on Google, the weird thing is even the pop-up was not displaying.

So why the `event.preventDefault();` was not working, and why the pop up is working on Firefox and not working on Chrome?

Comment: are you trying to prevent default on the actual form ?

Comment: what i mean was after displaying the `alert pop up`, it should not redirect to `/visit/something/`, but here event.preventDefault(); is not working it was allowing to redirect to `/visit/something/`

Comment: Working fine!! http://jsfiddle.net/6bQNM/ Tested in FF 28.0 and Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m.

Comment: oh its really wierd, it was redirecting me to `/visit/something/` without stopping it

Comment: This answer helped me for Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695472/2097494

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "event.preventDefault()" you should just use "return false".

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to preventdefault on while Submitting the form, not in  onClick. So better use return false behalf of event.preventDefault(). Though its working on other browser thats not correct way.

Comment: Who says its not the correct way? Source please. MDN seems to thinks it is the correct way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event