# How can I prevent form submission (page navigation) on artificial submit event in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox

Nothing I do seems to be able to prevent the form from loading a new page. I have the following test code:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false">
 <input id='input'>
 <input id='submit' type="button" value="click me">
</form>
<script>
 var form = document.getElementById("form")
 form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
   console.log("submit")
   ev.preventDefault()
   ev.returnValue = false
   return false
 })
 form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))
</script>
```

The page just loads and reloads over and over again. Is this a bug in firefox? I'm on version 60.7.0esr

Comment: removing `form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))` ??  and why do you have one ???

Comment: @MisterJojo Its for a unit test.

Comment: Try adding a {cancellable: true} to the event constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the event `cancelable` by adding a `cancelable` property to the `EventInit` Object that you need to pass to the `Event` constructor. It is `false` by default.

Consider [MDN Event Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#Values):

> `cancelable`: a `Boolean` indicating whether the event can be
>   cancelled. The default is `false`.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form")
form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
  console.log("submit")
  ev.preventDefault()
  ev.returnValue = false
  return false
})
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {
  cancelable: true
}))
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false">
  <input id='input'>
  <input id='submit' type="button" value="click me">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Firefox bug since at least 2017, cf. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1370630

Use the Event's `cancelable` property until the Firefox team fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

dispatch event forces to submit the form unless you make it cancelable. You can also add `<form onsubmit="return false">`
a quick solution would be:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false">
 <input id='input'>
 <input id='submit' type="button" value="click me">
</form>
<script>
 var form = document.getElementById("form")
 form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
   console.log("submit")
   ev.preventDefault()
   ev.returnValue = false
   return false
 })
 let event = new Event("submit", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
});
form.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Dispatching an event should not force submit of the form if the handlers prevent the default. Also, onsubmit="return false" does not solve the problem. The page still reloads.

Comment: @zero298 By the time I was checking the code I didn't see your one line comment. But for sure I now acknowledge that you had it right as well. Cheers!

Comment: e.preventDefault() resolved the issue in my case